# Microsoft graph get access without a user to get calendar events

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I create ASP.Net MVC application that use "get access without a user" scenario and I have granted all needed permission as application permission(Calendars.Read) using admin consent. I can already get token and can use that token to get user profile successfully. But, when I try to get calendar events data it get error code "AuthenticationError" and error message "Error authenticating with resource". I use C# code like this:

```
var events = await graphClient.Users[principalName].Events
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
```

Can Anyone suggest What things I missed or What permission I should use?

My code to get authentication is like this, finally I added "WithExtraQueryParameters" to ensure that I use grant_type is client_credentials

```
private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticated()
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = null;

        var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        query.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                            .Create(appId)
                            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, $"{tenantId}")
                            .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                            .WithExtraQueryParameters(query)
                            .Build();

        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(idClient);

        return new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async (requestMessage) => {
                var accounts = await idClient.GetAccountsAsync();
                if (accounts.Any())
                {
                    result = await idClient.AcquireTokenSilent(graphScopes?.Split(','), accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
                }
                else {
                    result = await idClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                }

                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            }
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Which provider do you use?

Comment: I use ClientCredentialProvider @Martin.Martinsson

Comment: it seems that error comes from your provider initialization. Please, share a code where you create auth provider (which you pass to the constructor of your graphClient)

Comment: Do you use  a tenant-id? (.WithTenantId(tenantId))

Comment: I update my code, how I get my access token from AD Azure @Serenkiy

Comment: I use my tenant-id @Martin.Martinsson

Comment: Your code is bloated. See down under.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding permissions: Calendars.ReadWrite, OnlineMeetings.Read.All, OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All

Comment: I already added Calendars.ReadWrite, OnlineMeetings.Read.All, OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All permissions. But, the error still appears

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what's wrong with your code. 
I can suggest you to use Microsoft graph SDK. Have a look at [Microsoft graph auth](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth). And don't forget about [Microsoft Identity client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/). Combining these two packages will simplify auth process and prevent you from such bugs.

If you decide to use them. Your auth would look like this:

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("client id")
                    .WithClientSecret("client secret")
                    .WithTenantId("your tenant id")
                    .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMyOrg)
                    .Build();
var authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(app);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

And then use `graphClient` for creating requests to the microsoft graph. Let me know if anything go wrong.

Comment: only can get user profile, like previous code.
when I use to get user profile like this graphClient.Users["user@user.onmicrosoft.com"].Request().GetAsync() it can return user objet. However, when I use graphClient.Users["user@user.onmicrosoft.com"].Events.Request().GetAsync() produces AuthenticationError

Answer (score 0):

```
var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

                var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClient));

                var evnts = await graphClient.Users["coyote@acme.com"].Events.Request().GetAsync();
```

This works when your client secret, tenant matches and you have set application permissions.

What does not work is this (ticket pending by me @MS):

```
    var tasks = await graphClient.Users["coyote@acme.com"].Outlook.Tasks
.Request()
.GetAsync();
```

Regards